# How can I keep hard edges with this shape?

Tags: modeling

I'm unsuccesfully tryning to keep the edges blunt, not too sharp for a more natural render by applying a Subsurf modifier. That's why I don't use the crease of 1. I tried to add an edge loop (CTRL+R) but can't on the top face. Thanks for your help.
[image]

[image]

Both answers work perfectly except for the following shape. I would like to soften the hard edges of the mesh. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to delete top faces, extrude rim and close the cup in different way, but if you want to keep quads, use bevel edge, by selecting outer edge and pressing CTRL+B and moving mouse to set bevel size.Her are both ways:
[image]

Comment: You don't need Laplacian. I just opened this panel by accident and closed it without using any of it. After closing this panel, I just extruded the edge and scaled it down, then extruded again, scaled down and CTRL+F >Grid Fill to fill empty space in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the edges on the face

[image: Base]

Add a loopcut on the edge like so

[image: Loopcut]

Select top face, press E and scale it inwards a bit

[image: Extruded]

Join the face's edges again

[image: Joined]

And apply SubSurf!

Comment: Probably quicker to use Inset (I) I think, or bevel with a profile of 1. Many ways to skin the cat :)

Comment: @Greg Zaal. what do you mean by Inset (I) I think, or bevel with a profile of 1?

Comment: Inset is a tool you can use on faces. In this case it's the same as extruding and scaling it in, but for more complex shapes it maintains the contours better. Bevel has some options if you hit F6 after using it; one of them is the profile, which adjusts the shape of the bevel; a profile of 1 means a 90° angle (usually) so it's the same as adding edge loops on each side (or insetting both face sets) but quicker.